# a:hover change background of list item

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get `a:hover` to change the background of a list item.

The approach I'm currently using only changes the immediate background color behind the text, not the entire space (`padding:15px 55px 15px 55px;`) assigned for that list item.

How do I go about changing the `a:hover` attributes to change the background color utilizing the full space assigned to that list item?

**CSS :**

```
 #navbar{
        background:#303030;
    }

#navbar li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 55px 15px 55px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;

}
#navbar a{
color:#F5F5F5;
}

#navbar a:hover{
background-color:#EE7621;
}
```

Comment: You can use `li:hover`...

Comment: Just FYI, `<a>` by default is not a block-level element, so that's why its not filling up the whole space. Padding doesn't effect it unless you set `display: block;` on the `<a>.` But as other just simply set the hover on the `<li>` instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not set your hover on the li:

```
#navbar li:hover{
background-color:#EE7621;
}
```

Edit:

As suggested by thirtydot:

"Ideally, your a element should take the entire space of your li element. Try adding display:inline-block; or display:block to the a and move the padding from the li to the a"

Comment: @Calgar99: Ideally, your `a` element should take the entire space of your `li` element. Try adding `display:inline-block;` or `display:block` to the `a` and move the padding from the `li` to the `a`.